# Facebook Graph API: get the full-size poster image for a video

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the full-size poster image for videos in the Facebook Graph API. For example;

**Facebook post:** https://www.facebook.com/8245623462_10153166780183463

**Facebook API:**  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=8245623462_10153166780183463&version=v2.3&

**Picture link in the API:**  https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhvthumb-ak-xpa1%2Fv%2Ft15.0-10%2Fs130x130%2F11188535_10153166806463463_1047327156_n.jpg%3Foh%3Db4b278ddf507529f68dca0c8cf28499f%26oe%3D55D7BF31%26__gda__%3D1443263230_3573aca254b0c1017a27330f9f1ca65b&h=gAQHTKGXt

Does anyone have any pointers or ideas on how I might be able to get the full-size image for the video rather than the tiny thumbnail?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try explicitly requesting the `full_picture` field of the [API request](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=8245623462_10153166780183463%3Ffields%3Dfull_picture&version=v2.3&)

Comment: Dude, you're a legend! It works like a charm! Out of curiosity, how did you find out about the 'full_picture' field? I can't find it anywhere in the Facebook API docs.

Comment: I couldn't find documentation on it as well, but I found it by playing with the fields on the left, and there was a `full_picture` field. It seems there's a lot of undocumented functionality for various graph objects.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely a bit of a headache to find concrete info on a lot of stuff in the API. Thank goodness for Stack Overflow. Thanks again for the help!